# How to format the Cumulative Sum of List created without Itertools or Functools

Tags: string-formatting, cumulative-sum, python-3.10

```
num_list = [12, 16, 17, 2, 5, 19, 24, 27, 42]
```

Hello, I'm trying to format the cumulative sum of a list of numbers created without itertools. This is the code I have so far. I would like each number in the cumulative list to have a width of 10 when printed, but I am not sure how.

```
def Cumulative(lists):
num_list = []
length = len(lists)
num_list = [sum(lists[0:x:1]) for x in range(0, length+1)]
return num_list[1:]
print (Cumulative(num_list))
```

F string formatting obviously proved to be unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use f-strings to format each list item (integer) *within* text.

The syntax of the alignment of the output string is defined by `>`

Example:

```python
f"{number : >10}"  # this aligns the number to the right, with a width of 10
```

Similarly, in your code, you can use this formatting on the result of the `sum()` inside your list comprehension:

```python
num_list = [12, 16, 17, 2, 5, 19, 24, 27, 42]


def cumulative_sum(lists):
    length = len(lists)
    new_list = [f"{sum(lists[0:x]) : >10}" for x in range(0, length+1)]
    return new_list[1:]


print(cumulative_sum(num_list))
```

The output will be:

```python
['        12', '        28', '        45', '        47', '        52', '        71', '        95', '       122', '       164']
```

This will satisfy your requirement:

> I would like each number in the cumulative list to have a width of 10 when printed

**Note**: now the the list is made up of strings, not integers

**Alternatively**:

If you don't want to change the type of each item, then you can keep the function returning the list of integers.

You can add the f-string alignment formatting around each list item as you print them. For example:

```python
for num in cumulative_sum(num_list):
     print(f"{num : >10}")
```

Output:

```python
        12
        28
        45
        47
        52
        71
        95
       122
       164
```